# If a coin is flipped $10$ times, what are the possibilities of getting at least $5$ H?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> If a coin is flipped $10$ times what are the possibilities of getting at least $5$H?

Is a pascal triangle really needed to do this type of questions?

Comment: You can use Pascal's triangle only to compute combinitorial coefficients. And to find the answer consider all the cases possible and add the probability of all cases at last.

Comment: There was a test and I wrote 639 as the answer, can anyone help me compute this?

Comment: How could $639$ be a probability?

Comment: If you don't want to sum five terms (not too difficult, really), then work from symmetry.  The probability that you get more than $5$ Heads is the same as the probability of getting less than $5$, so all you need to do is compute the probability of getting exactly $5$.

Comment: Because the question asked was how many ways to get at least 5H if a coin is flipped 10 times, and I said 638, is this correct or wrong im not quite sure thats why im asking you guys

Comment: Ah i see Lulu but the problem i was asked to try to solve it using the pascal triangle or the tree diagram

Comment: I have yet to try your method

Comment: Well, if you are required to do it that way, then I'm not sure what you are asking.  If you just want to check the number, then Yes.  $638$ is correct.

Comment: Ahh ok then thx lulu

Comment: To do it my way:  $\binom {10}5 = 252$ and $\frac {2^{10}-252}2=386$.  We then check that $252+386=638$.

Comment: Ahh ok then thx for the answer and working

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach to the problem:

If there are exactly $5$ heads,

This can be done in ${10\choose 5}$ ways.
Of the remaining $2^{10}-{10\choose 5}$ cases, half of the time, there are more heads than tails and half of the time there are more tails than heads.

Thus, there are $\frac{2^{10}-{10\choose 5}}{2}$ ways in this case with more than 5 heads. Adding them, we get $\frac{2^{10}-{10\choose 5}}{2}+{10\choose 5}=2^9+\frac{{10\choose 5}}{2}$ ways with at least 5 heads.